# Copy sheet to new spreadsheet, Add cell value to end of new spreadsheet name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is now creating the copy and adding the text to the end of the file name. The new file is located in the same directory as the original file. I can't seem to move the new file to the "Timesheet Archive" folder. Seems like I should just be able to specify the location for the new file?

```
var range = sheet.getRange(2,7); 
var data = range.getValue();
var SSID = '1S3Vj5lYOchh0OJ5ZCamsoMCKtcTHeFd72nyxPHJYofk'
var CopyDate = Utilities.formatDate(data , "GMT-8", "yy_MM_dd"); 
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Timesheet Archive'); 
var id = DriveApp.getFileById(SSID)
id.makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate);
```

I am moving to Google's new Sheets and am having trouble with this function which was working fine prior to the move:

```
function exportData() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Timesheet");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  sourceData.splice(0,1);  // Remove header

  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZKQw9WnAFmJfC6GP_CYmSbQK_820zIR6oQGnLMc1yBM").getSheetByName("Master Time Sheet");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Timesheet');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = ss.getName();  // Not necessary 

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Timesheet'); // or whatever is the name of the sheet 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,7); 
  var data = range.getValue();

  var SSID = '1S3Vj5lYOchh0OJ5ZCamsoMCKtcTHeFd72nyxPHJYofk'
  var CopyDate = Utilities.formatDate(data , "GMT-8", "yy_MM_dd"); // Function Date + Format

  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Timesheet Archive'); //Use this line if you want to get the folder by name
  var backup = DocsList.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate);

  backup.addToFolder(folder); //This line will move the file
  backup.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder()); //This line is needed to remove the File from the Root
}
```

The first part copies part of the sheet to another existing spreadsheet and this part of the function is working properly. The second part copies the entire sheet, creates a new file using this copied sheets name and data and appends the end of the file name using text (a date) from a cell located on the source sheet. It is supposed to first move it to the root folder and then to another folder titled "Timesheet Archive".

I am not getting any errors and the file is not appearing in either the root folder nor in the "Timesheet Archive" folder.

Comment: You are defining `var sheet` twice.

Comment: `DocsList` is deprecated.  Better to use `DriveApp`.

Comment: For purposes of debugging, I'd break up this line into smaller parts:  `var backup = DocsList.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate);`  You can always chain it back together later if you want.

Comment: First, The original code did work, it only took 10+ minutes to show up. I'm guessing this has to do with Sandy's second comment. Second, I am close with: `var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Timesheet Archive'); var backup = DriveApp.getFileById(SSID).makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate);` it creates the copy but I can't seem to copy it to the specified folder and delete the original –

Comment: Better to post your updated code into the original question.  Maybe leave the original code, but post the updated code at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using:

```
DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Timesheet Archive');
```

That gets a "Folder Iterator"

You need to either use:

```
getFolderById(id)
```

Or iterate through the folders, (Even though there may only be one!)

```
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  if (folder === 'Timesheet Archive') {
    //Make copy here
    
  };
}
```

There is no `addToFolder()` method of the File Class.  `backup` is a file.  The `makeCopy()` method has a `destination` option.  You can create the backup and put it into the destination all at the same time.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)

Use your `folder` variable, that is a folder type as the destination.

Comment: It's coming up with this error "Cannot find method makeCopy(string,FolderIterator)." I'm using `id.makeCopy(SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID).getName() + "_" + CopyDate, folder);` in the updated top code section.

Comment: I used getFolderById(id). Simple. Thanks